# VB Masked Textbox Loses Digit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, time, masking, maskedtextbox

I have a masked textbox in VB.NET to input a time value.  I've tried the masks 90:00, 00:00, and ##:##.  The first time a value is entered in the box, it inputs fine.  I later clear the text with

```
mskTime.Text = ""
```

I've also tried

```
mskTime.Clear()
mskTime.ResetText()
```

The issue is after the text is cleared and a new time is entered, the first character typed is deleted.  More precisely, when I add the time 12:34, I type the 1, it appears in the first character slot.  I then press 2, and the 1 disappears and the 2 appears in the second character slot.  The character does not disappear when you go to type it again to fix it.

Has anyone seen this issue or know why the first character disappears?

Comment: It certainly sounds like you are firing an event handler unknowingly. The easiest way to tell when and what is firing is to set break points in Visual Studio and step through your code as you interact with the UI ([how to link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1777MupP_A)). If that doesn't resolve the issue, you should probably post more code for us to get a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found:

I had a KeyDown function to handle the user pressing enter in the time field:

```
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Schedule()
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
```

Commenting out

```
e.SuppressKeyPress = True
```

solves the issue.  I originally used that to prevent Windows from making a ding sound each time enter was pressed.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the ding sound. its all to do with event processing and how far down the nest it goes into Windows to then process that key press if it gets down that far

Comment: Any suggestions on how to remove the dinging a different way? That's what I found after Googling around.

Comment: I removed the dinging by switching to KeyPress from KeyDown and using e.handled = True

Comment: you do realise the dinging sound is part of the Windows sound system profile, right?

Comment: Yes, but I want to suppress it from occurring in select cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem in C#. The input worked fine until the `MaskedTextBox` was cleared programmatically. After that the first character entered in one of the `MaskedTextBoxes` was deleted after a second character has been entered. Turned out that the problem lied within the `KeyDown` event. I was waiting for the `Enter`-Key there, did some stuff and cleared the `TextBoxes`. After that, the problem occured.

I solved it now by replacing the `KeyDown`-Event with a `KeyPress`-Event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up using to catch the Enter Key and move to the next field and not screw up the masked textbox when I come back to it.
Douglas

```
    private void TxtLocID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
        }
    }
```